# How do I know the span of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

I have a marix that is 
$$R=\pmatrix{1&1&1\\1&1&1+2a\\0&2&2+2b}$$

and the span of R is   span=$\left\{\pmatrix{1\\1\\0},\pmatrix{0\\0\\1}\right\}$

In my preliminery thinking, the span is the combination of vectors that indicate each vector in R, but in reverse, If I know a matrix, how can I derive the span?

Could anyone tell me I can I calculate the span of a matrix

Taking this as an example, how can I get to this result?

Comment: You should include your thoughts and efforts in this and future posts. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Note that $span\left(\left[ \begin{smallmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{smallmatrix} \right],\left[ \begin{smallmatrix}0\\0\\1 \end{smallmatrix}\right]\right) =  span\left(\left[ \begin{smallmatrix}1\\1\\0 \end{smallmatrix}\right], \left[ \begin{smallmatrix}1\\1\\2 \end{smallmatrix}\right]\right)$ is nothing more than the span of the first two columns.  In general it is the span of *all* columns, but you may opt not to include redundancies.  Without knowing the values of $a$ and $b$ however, it is possible that the span of your specific matrix is larger however.

Comment: For example, when $a=-\frac{1}{2}$ and $b=-1$, the third column is linearly independent to the other two and the image of the matrix is all of $\Bbb R^3$

Comment: What definition of span are you using? The definition of span I'm aware is [linear span](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_span#Definition). Are you perhaps asking what matrices span the space of matrices of type $R$? If so your example is far from it. You give example of 3-dimensional vectors, while matrix $R$ is a vector of 9-dimensioanl space. Elaboration is much needed here.

Comment: The span of the _column space_ is not simply that set of two vectors; rather the span of the column space is the SPAN OF that set of two vectors.  That set of two vectors is a basis of the span.  The set of two vectors is not the span itself. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2):

You do not speak about span of matrices (in a vector space where matrix considered an abstract vector). In your case you should speak about column space $col(R)=Span\{R_{\downarrow j}\}_{j=1}^n$ or row space $row(R)=Span\{R_{i\rightarrow}\}_{i=1}^m$ of a matrix. There is also another related space, a null space, i.e. $Null(A)=\{x|Ax=0\}$.

The Span's argument, i.e. the set in the curly brackets may be reduced in case of the vectors, columns or rows respectively, are not linearly independent. More precisely you can remove any linearly dependent vector without changing the space this set spans.

Now to find the linearly independent vectors you simply produce with matrix
reduction. For the rows you throw away the zero rows. For the columns only the pivot columns are linearly independent.

Comment: spanned of a matrix is well defined. If $U=\{A_1,...,A_n\}$, where all $A_i$ has same dimensions with entries in a common field $\mathbb{K}$, then $span(U)=\{a_1A_1+...+a_nA_b|a_i\in\mathbb{K}\}$,

Comment: you right, but  this is not what OP mentioned anyway

Answer (score 1):

Your question is ambiguous, cause in general, for fixed $n,m$, the set $S=M_{n\times m}(\mathbb{K})$ (matrices of $n\times m$ with entries in the field $\mathbb{K}$) is a vector space over $\mathbb{K}$. Then, if $A\in S$, definition of $span(A)$ is the usual definition for span of a vector in $S$.

However, I suppose indeed in your problem you are asking for the column space spanned by a matrix. i.e. the space spanned for the columns of the matrix.

Then, you are searching for $V=span\{(1,1,0)^T,(1,1,2)^T,(1,1+2a,1+2b)^T\}$ and, by hypothesis, this is $span\{(1,1,0)^T,(0,0,1)^T\}$.

As vectors $(1,1,0)^T,(0,0,1)^T$ are linearly independents, you need that $(0,0,1)^T$ let a linear combination of $(1,1,2)^T,(1,1+2a,1+2b)^T$. That is, find $x,y$ such that

$$
\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}x+y&=&0\\x+y(1+2a)&=&0\\2x+y(1+2b)&=&1\end{array}\right.
$$

for given $a,b$.

Solving for $x$ and $y$, we get, for $a\neq 0$, there are not $x,y$. For $a=0$, and $b=-3/2$, there are not solutions, and for $a=0$ and $b\neq -3/2$, $x=-1/(3+2b)$ and $y=1/(3+2b)$

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $\pmatrix{ 1 \\ 1 \\ 2} = 1\cdot \pmatrix{ 1 \\ 1 \\ 0} + 2\cdot \pmatrix{0 \\ 0 \\ 1}$, and $\pmatrix{1 \\ 1+ 2a\\ 2+ 2b} = 1\cdot \pmatrix{1 \\ 1 \\0}+(2+2b)\cdot \pmatrix{0 \\ 0 \\1} + 2a\cdot \pmatrix{0 \\ 1 \\0}$, and also $\text{det}\pmatrix{1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 1 & 0}= -1 \neq 0$, thus $R$ is spanned by $\pmatrix{1 \\ 1 \\ 0}$, $\pmatrix{0 \\ 0 \\1}$, and $\pmatrix{0 \\ 1 \\ 0}$.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're meant to find the values of $a$ and $b$ that give the column space $$\mathrm{col}(R)=\mathrm{span}\left\{\pmatrix{1\\1\\0},\pmatrix{0\\0\\1}\right\}=\left\{\pmatrix{r\\r\\s}:r,s \in \mathbb{R}\right\}.$$

We can immediately see that $a$ must be $0$, otherwise the third column of $R$ has different values in its first and second coordinate, which is not in the above span.

When $a=0$, $$R=\pmatrix{1&1&1\\1&1&1\\0&2&2+2b},$$ and all three columns of $R$ can be seen to belong to $\mathrm{col}(R)$ (set$r=1$ and $s=0$, $1$ or $2+2b$ accordingly), so $b$ can be any value in $\mathbb{R}$.